# mount command pid

Tags: python, mount, pid

Trying to mount a device and get the pid of mount command.

> cmd="/bin/mount /dev/sda1 /mnt"
>
> os.system(cmd)

Now how to obtain the pid of mount command? There plenty of mounted device available on my system, something like  `ps | grep mount`  won't work.

Comment: Why do you need the PID?  The mount command will complete and control will return to the Python script before you can do anything about using the PID for it.  In particular, you are unlikely to be able to find it in the 'ps' listings.

Comment: I thought using pid i can kill the mount process - ie using pid i would like to umount it. that's not possible?

Comment: nopey, that's what umount(8) is for.

Comment: The mount command executes the mount() system call and exits.  The file system stays mounted even though the process that did the mounting has terminated.  As @msw notes, the umount command is used to execute the umount() system call to unmount a file system.  Further, if the mount command did hang around, you would have to wait until it died before the the os.system() statement/function returned to your script - unless the mount command did its work by daemonizing itself (fork, parent exits, child remains to do its stuff).  However, that is not necessary, so the mount command does not do it.

Comment: thanks for the clarification ..I'll close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments suggest I'm not sure how useful it is to get the mount pid, but if you use the *subprocess* module you can easily get the pid.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen("ls", shell=True)
>>> p.pid
4136
>>>
```